# how to revert back to default settings of make menuconfig

Tags: linux, embedded

I am using ridgerun sdk..I made some settings in the config file through the command "make menuconfig"(but now i dont remember what settings i made). Now I want to cancel those settings in the config file and want the default settings. But the command "make mrproper" is not supported by Ridgerun sdk.Please suggest some solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

The previous config file is renamed as `.config.old` Just copy it over the newer one

```
cp .config.old .config
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming RidgeRun SDK uses some derivative of the Linux kernel's kbuild then deleting (make sure to back it up first, of course!) the .config file in the build system's root folder will do the trick.